# How to fix Xcode version 11.0 beta canvas crash?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I'm following the https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials for SwiftUI and I've downloaded both **macOS Catalina and Xcode 11.0 beta.**

Canvas crashed and doesn't restore even after trying the following:

- I've tried completely cleaning the project - failed
- I've tried restarting Xcode - failed
- I've tried rebooting - failed

The code simply declares the UI, nothing too fancy.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkDetail : View {
    var landmark: Landmark

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView(coordinate: landmark.locationCoordinate)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .frame(height: 300)

            CircleImage(image: landmark.image(forSize: 250))
                .offset(y: -130.0)
                .padding(.bottom, -130.0)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(landmark.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)


                HStack {
                    Text(landmark.park)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(landmark.state)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(landmark.name), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmarkData[0])
    }
}
#endif
```

I expect the canvas to show the UI, but I keep getting the `Cannot preview in this file --- MyApp.app may have crashed` error.

Here is an image of what that looks like:

[image: Canvas crash]

**Please note that everything was working fine until a certain point.**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What happens when you delete the last lines added, or when you start a new project all together?

Comment: What happens if you run on simulator/device? I incurred in a crash because of the JSON decoding, but the canvas is not able to show those kind of errors, so I discovered after running on a simulator

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio
Yeah, I get this error when I try to run the app: 
`Fatal error: Couldn't parse landmarkData.json as Array<Landmark>:`

Which is weird, since everything worked fine... I haven't touched the JSON file at all... 

Did you have the same issue, and if so, how did you go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I incurred your same error; I fixed by downloading the updated resources from the tutorial. Basically I think you added `isFavorite` to the `Landmark` model, but in the JSON that field is missing, so it is failing the decode. Download the and replace the new JSON from the tutorial assets.

If the problem is not `isFavorite`, should be another resource missing, just be sure to download the new `Landmark` model and the associated resources every time you start a new lesson from the tuorial.

This is Apple fault, as they didn't mention that you need to update the JSON file to match the `Landmark` model.

**EDIT**

If you still have problem, just add your json and your `Landmark` model here so we can take a look on them

Comment: Yep, that was the issue...
After getting the updated Resources, everything worked like a charm.

Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

The above is correct however after updating the JSON to match the resources one from Apple I still had a crash. In this JSON their is also a new category "Mountains" you will have to update the Landmark.swift to include the below case also.

```
enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Hashable {
        case featured = "Featured"
        case lakes = "Lakes"
        case rivers = "Rivers"
        case mountains = "Mountains"
}
```

Also make sure you have included all the bundled images (attached for reference). I was missing a couple between the first couple of tutorials from Apple. Seems there are inconsistencies in following along rather than downloading the resources.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the first crash is related to the enum Category case that was added in Landmark.swift:

```
enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Hashable {
    case featured = "Featured"
    case lakes = "Lakes"
    case rivers = "Rivers"
    case mountains = "Mountains" . // <- added
}
```

The second crash that follows is due to resource name changing:
If you don't want to update the resources just make sure to rename the yukon_charleyrivers.jpg to 'charleyrivers.jps' or just make sure it matches the .json "imageName" value for the Charley Rivers dictionary.

```
{
    "name": "Charley Rivers",
    "category": "Rivers",
    "city": "Eaking",
    "state": "Alaska",
    "id": 1007,
    "isFeatured": true,
    "isFavorite": false,
    "park": "Charley Rivers National Preserve",
    "coordinates": {
        "longitude": -143.122586,
        "latitude": 65.350021
    },
    "imageName": "charleyrivers",  // <- changed from yukon_charleyrivers
}
```